# WHY Gauss-Jordan method inverses matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know that we start with $[A | I]$ matrix and after applying the method it becomes $[I | A^{-1}]$. My question is why this happens? Have we proved it or so? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is because elementary operations on the rows of a matrix correspond to multiplying on the left by an invertible matrix (called a matrix of elementary operation). Thus after a finite number of steps, you obtain
$$E_k E_{k-1}\dotsm E_1[\mkern1mu A\;I\mkern2mu]=[\mkern1mu E_k E_{k-1}\dotsm E_1A\;E_k E_{k-1}\dotsm E_1I\mkern2mu]=[\mkern1mu I\;E_k E_{k-1}\dotsm E_1].$$
By identification, you obtain that the submatrix made up of the last $n$ columns is the inverse of $A$:
$$E_k E_{k-1}\dotsm E_1=A^{-1}.$$

Comment: Could  columns be taken as well ? I wonder , why rows are more popular for elementary operations than columns ..

Comment: @Widawensen: You can operate on columns as well (it corresponds in this case to multiplying by an invertible matrix on the right at each step), but you can't do both types of operations. Rows are more often used because of linear systems solving: operations on rows means making linear combinations of equations, whereas operations on columns means linear combinations of the unknowns.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation of the problem.. Now I know..

Answer (score 1):

The reason this happens is because when you reduce $A$ to the identity by a sequence of row operations, each row operation corresponds to multiplication on the left by some elementary matrix.

So if you have a sequence of row operations applied $R_1,...,R_n$ applied one after another to $A$, and if the corresponding elementary matrices are $M_1,...,M_n$, then when $A$ is reduced to the identity we obtain the equation
$$M_n ... M_1 \, A = I
$$
Multiplying both sides of this equation on the right by $A^{-1}$ we obtain
$$M_n ... M_1 \,I = A^{-1}
$$
This means that if you apply the row operations $R_1,...,R_n$ one after another to $I$ then you get $A^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Doing a row operation corresponds to multiplying from the right with a certain [elementary matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix). Gaussian elimination can be viewed as a systematic way to find a sequence of elementary matrices such that
$$ B_n\cdots B_2 B_1 A = I $$
when $A$ has full rank. Thus, by definition, the product $B=B_n\cdots B_1$ is the inverse of $A$.

Now multiplying a matrix from the left corresponds to transforming the *columns* of the right-hand factor one by one. So we generally have
$$ B[A\;C] = [BA\;BC]$$
whenever each of $A$ and $C$ have the right number of rows. Setting $C$ to $I$ we get
$$ B[A\;I] = [I\;B]$$
because (as argued above) $B$ is the inverse of $A$. So instead of writing out the elementary matrices and multiplying them one by one you can recover them by simply doing the same row operations on a copy of the identity matrix.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is an invertibel $n\times n$ matrix, the $k^{\text{th}}$ column $a_k$ of $A^{-1}$ is the solution of $Aa_k=e_k$, where $e_k$ is the $k^{\text{th}}$ unit vector.

To calculate all columns of $A^{-1}$ one has to solve the $n$ linear systems $[A|e_k]$ for $k=1,\dots,n$.  Fortunately one may solve them simultaneously by calculating $[A|I]$.