# Can I get a matrix's inverse from elementary column operations?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, gaussian-elimination

In my class we've been talking about elementary row operations of matrices, for example, to get its inverse. I remember the teacher saying, those operations don't work for columns; however, in my book, it says they do work. Can I use them on columns to get to the identity matrix for instance, so that I can, then, get its inverse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Gauss-Jordan method is based on rows operations by

$$A^{-1}\cdot (A|I)=(I|A^{-1})$$

we can also operate by columns operation that is

$$\begin{pmatrix}A\\I\end{pmatrix}A^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}I\\A^{-1}\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: I haven't seen both of those equations. Is the first one the same as $A.A^{-1}=I=A^{-1}.A$? If so, I understand that for that operation, the rows should be used and the columns can't? What is the second equation then?

Comment: @DuarteArribas Since rows operation are equivalent to left matrix multiplicationwe can summarize the method by $A^{-1}\cdot (A|I)=(I|A^{-1})$. We can of course operate by columns operations which correspond to roght matrix multiplication. For more details refer also to this [OP](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2735815/505767).

Comment: @DuarteArribas To emphasize the point here, column operations work, too, but you have to augment the matrix by appending $I$ _below_ it instead of to the right.